# Service fabric local cluster error

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I m getting the following error on my local service fabric cluster node:

> Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting', Property='Activation:1.0'.
>   There was an error during activation.Failed to setup
>   ApplicationPrincipals. Error:ApplicationPrincipalAbortableError

There is no much logs other than that, I m running VS2017 on Windows 10 with

service fabric tools version:
**3.0.480.9494**

service fabric runtime version:
**6.1.480.9494**

I executed the following for service fabric powershell scripts:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser
```

Everything is run as adminstrator.
There is no errors in VS app creation and deployement output on my local cluster...
I couldn't find much help on google..

I d be gratefull for some help.

Regards,
Lokman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it is often related to privilege issues, or after checking my ApplicationManifest.xml, tried changing the Users section:

```
 <Users>
      <User Name="xxxx">
        <MemberOf>
          <SystemGroup Name="Administrators" />
        </MemberOf>
      </User>
    </Users>
```

My windows was in french so Administrators was spelled wrongly (Administrateurs in french).